# How to get hostnames from a SoftLayer order

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When SoftLayer hardware servers are ordered with the `placeOrder()` API call, the hostnames are provided as part of the `Product_Order` value, and an orderId is returned.  Is there a way to retrieve the hostnames from the order using the orderId?

I was able to find the order by looking through the list returned by  `client['Account'].getOrders()`.  However, that does not give me any order details (see below).  I looked through the list of SoftLayer Services and methods, but could not seem to find the answer.

**order retrieved from SoftLayer (note there are no hostnames or other details)**

`{'accountId': 999999,
 'createDate': '2017-03-20T12:00:00-07:00',
 'id': 21212121,
 'impersonatingUserRecordId': '',
 'modifyDate': '2017-03-20T12:00:00-07:00',
 'orderQuoteId': '',
 'orderTypeId': 4,
 'presaleEventId': '',
 'privateCloudOrderFlag': False,
 'status': 'APPROVED',
 'userRecordId': 757575}`

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to dig through the SoftLayer documentation, I was able to find a solution. It involves retrieving the items from the [Billing_Order](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order) to get at the hostnames on the order.

**Sample code that works**

```
for item in client['Billing_Order'].getItems(id=orderid):
    if 'hostName' in item:
        print item['hostName']
```